# CMD says ReferenceError: run is not defined for the following code

Tags: discord.js

I want to make a bot which joins a discord voice channel and for my code, I combined [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXohhIJ1-f4) video with [this](https://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/how-to-make-a-discord-bot/) video

This is my `bot.js` file:

```js
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});

bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    // Our bot needs to know if it will execute a command
    // It will listen for messages that will start with `!`

    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];
        args = args.splice(1);

        switch(cmd) {
            // !ping
            case 'cf':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'sunt viu, dude!'
                });
                break;
        
            case 'join':
                run(message); {
                    const { voice } = message.member
                    if (!voice.channelID) {
                        message.reply('trebuie sa fi pe ceva canal voice')
                        return
                    }
                    voice.channel.join()
                }
                break;
        // Just add any case commands if you want to.
         }

    }
});
```

and this is the error I get:

```js
> ReferenceError: run is not defined
    at DiscordClient.<anonymous> (D:\RadioTinBot\bot.js:71:13)
    at DiscordClient.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at DiscordClient.handleWSMessage (D:\RadioTinBot\node_modules\discord.io\lib\index.js:1854:11)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Receiver.ontext (D:\RadioTinBot\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:841:10)
    at D:\RadioTinBot\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:536:18
    at Receiver.applyExtensions (D:\RadioTinBot\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:371:5)
    at D:\RadioTinBot\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:508:14
    at Receiver.flush (D:\RadioTinBot\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:347:3)
    at Receiver.finish (D:\RadioTinBot\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:541:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `run` function is not defined in your code, you've to define it or to remove it from your code.

Be careful, you're using a lot of discord.js deprecated features, here's the [discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/general/welcome) of the latest stable version.

Comment: if i remove the run, what do i use instead?

Comment: Put the code that the `run` function execute, but I can't help more if you haven't got any coding skills and you only copy paste codes that you found.